# How to populate an array using gets.chomp

Tags: ruby, arrays

Here's what I have so far:

```
#Table of Contents using an array
title = "Table of Consents"

#Needs chapters inputted
chapters = Array.new

puts "Please input chapter names."

while gets.chomp != ""
  chapter = gets.chomp
  chapters.push chapter
  break if gets.chomp.empty?
end

#Needs corresponding page numbers inputted
pagenumbers = Array.new

puts "Please input corresponding page numbers."

while gets.chomp != ""
  pagenum = gets.chomp
  pagenumbers.push pagenum
  break if gets.chomp.empty?        
end

puts chapters
puts page numbers
```

I'm trying to get `gets.chomp` to continue adding to each array. When I push `chapter` or `pagenum`, I only get the last string/integer input. How do I get each input to populate the `chapter` or `pagenum` array?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I corrected the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that every single time you write `gets` in your program, you are calling the `gets` method, which fetches a line of input from the user.  You need to store that line somewhere so it can be used later.  Try something like this:

```
chapters = []
while true
  input = gets.chomp
  break if input.empty?
  chapters << input
end
puts "Chapters: " + chapters.join(", ")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This makes sense! Does << assign input to chapters in the array?

Comment: The `<<` is called the insertion operator and you can see the documentation here:  http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C